# Know which page was clicked with Google CSE?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-custom-search

I have Google CSE in my webiste for monitoring how is searched with Google Analytics.

Use Google CSE code and add this (for monitoring it with anlytics):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];  
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1 ']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

However in google analytics i can see only:

1. searched words
2. first page (where user make the search)

I can't see which result (and page) is clicked by user after a search in google cse

Is a way to monitor this ???

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google CSEs but I presume you would need event tracking to track clicks to links. The code you show is for creating the GA tracker and sending a pageview. Are the CSE results in an iframe or what...

Comment: hmm is possible, but i hope that there's a code of CSE to monitor track clicks to results links...i wait :)

Comment: That code you posted definitely won't track clicks for you.